# Android - image on top of all

Tags: java, android, service

my first post here.

I want to have untouchable image on top of all user activity like using others apps, or phoning etc. all times. Image should only display, nothing more. Everything else should  functioning normally.
I have problem how to implement this image exactly, i know that i have to use Service, and i  use it in my code. I found [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4481226/creating-a-system-overlay-always-on-top-button-in-android), this is similar to what i want get but with picture not text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think its not much difference from the text.
Just use one of the drawBitmap functions instead of drawText in the Canvas class to do it. 
 
ie.:

```
 protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, 5, 15, mLoadPaint);
 }
```

(I'm referencig the linked question here)

Answer (score 1):

I doubt a `Service` will be of any help here, but you can actually implement this behavior using a single `Activity` and a number of `Fragments`. Just use a `FrameLayout` for your `Activity's` layout and put an `ImageView` on top of the container that will hold `Fragments`.

Comment: Yes sure, but i want to use others phone functions when this image on top, in your solve when i exit the Activity then image will disappear. In my linked solution user can do everything while text is dispplaying. service is necessary because of control of image (when it can be display when not, only Service has control). But maybe i'm wrong this is my first app. Sorry for my English